# Show file directory inside input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery based file listing

Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#fileTreeDemo_2').fileTree({
root: '../../',
script: 'connectors/jqueryFileTree.php',
folderEvent: 'click',
expandSpeed: 750,
collapseSpeed: 750,
multiFolder: false
},
function(file){
alert(file);
});
});
</script>

<div id="fileTreeDemo_2"></div>
```

Results :
It shows files list and when i choose file, it trigger `function(file)` and gives alert `alert(file);`

[image: Alert]

Now the question, What if i want to add `input` field where the chosen file directory rather than giving me alert `alert(file);` it show it inside that `input` field as shown in this image

[image: Input]

so i just want to modify `function(file){ alert(file); });` to show the content of this `alert` inside `input` field that has `id="dir"` with that code

```
<input type="text" name="something" id="dir">
```

~ Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function showName(file) {
    $("#dir").val(file);
}
```